# TO_WKTGEOMETRY doesn't seem to work with multipolygons (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, spatial

I'm using `Oracle Database 11.2`.  I've loaded a geometry column with multipolygons, using `sdo_elem_info_array` and `sdo_ordinate_array` variables. But when I try to retrieve the text version of the shapes, I just get `MULTIPOLYGON ()`.

This block illustrates my problem:

```
DECLARE
    v_elem_info_array sdo_elem_info_array;
    v_ordinate_array sdo_ordinate_array;
    v_boundary sdo_geometry;
BEGIN
    -- This works:
    dbms_output.put_line(SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY( SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKTGEOMETRY('MULTIPOLYGON(((-109.2693 45.00528,-104.0577 44.99743,-104.05325 41.0014,-111.04673 40.99795,-111.0552 45.00132,-109.2693 45.00528)))')));

    -- This does not work:
    v_elem_info_array := sdo_elem_info_array();
    v_ordinate_array := sdo_ordinate_array();

    v_elem_info_array.extend(3);
    v_elem_info_array(1) := 1;
    v_elem_info_array(2) := 103;
    v_elem_info_array(3) := 1;

    v_ordinate_array.extend(12);
    v_ordinate_array(1) := -109.2693;
    v_ordinate_array(2) := 45.00528;
    v_ordinate_array(3) := -104.0577;
    v_ordinate_array(4) := 44.99743;
    v_ordinate_array(5) := -104.05325;
    v_ordinate_array(6) := 41.0014;
    v_ordinate_array(7) := -111.04673;
    v_ordinate_array(8) := 40.99795;
    v_ordinate_array(9) := -111.0552;
    v_ordinate_array(10) := 45.00132;
    v_ordinate_array(11) := -109.2693;
    v_ordinate_array(12) := 45.00528;

    v_boundary := sdo_geometry (2007, 8307, null, v_elem_info_array, v_ordinate_array);

    dbms_output.put_line(SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(v_boundary));
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is with your construction of SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY, should it not be 1003 to indicate an exterior polygon?

```
v_elem_info_array := sdo_elem_info_array(1, 1003, 1);
```